# Getting parent tty

Tags: linux, process, parent-child

Is there an easier way to get the parents terminal tty-info, of a currently running process,  without evaluating the process with `ps afx`?
An other solution to show parent-child-relations of terminal (windows) would be fine too.

Comment: On which platform? For Linux or OS X, you can probably find the source code of "ps" and see how it is done.